# My app behaves different on iPad than iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I created an app on xcode and tested it on iOS Simulator and it worked as I wanted. I now connected an iPad so I can test on it. When I run the app on iPad it behaves different. Some functionality that was not on iOS Simulator is on iPad. Some of it does not work at all. Is it some compatibility issue or something else?

My app basically consist of dragging `imageViews` on another `ImageView` which acts as an answer box and counts the number of `imageViews` of that were dragged. I have different types of `imageViews` to be dragged on different answer `imageViews`. If you drag to incorrect `imageView` you loose points and that `imageView` resets back to its original position. Running it on iPad you can drag 1 `imageView` to the correct answer `imageView` and then simply tap on the answer `imageView` to get maximum points(this should not happen) also after releasing the dragged `imageView` it suppose to reset back to its original position unless it reaches the destination, but on iPad it does not. And dragging one `imageView` on the correct answer `imageView` it adds one to other answer `imageView` and it should not

code for dragging the buttons:

```
    for (UIImageView *symbol in symbols1) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(symbol.frame ,answer1.frame)) {
            symbol.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            symbol.hidden = YES;
            intersectionCount1++;
            score1=score1+10;
            break;
        }
        else if (CGRectIntersectsRect(symbol.frame, answer2.frame)){
            symbol.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            symbol.hidden = NO;
            score1=score1-10;
            break;
        }
        else if (CGRectIntersectsRect(symbol.frame, answer3.frame)){
            symbol.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            symbol.hidden = NO;
            score1=score1-10;
            break;
        }
        else if (CGRectIntersectsRect(symbol.frame, answer4.frame)){
            symbol.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            symbol.hidden = NO;
            score1=score1-10;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (intersectionCount1 == 1) {
        UIImage *Pic1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number1.png"];
        [correctCounter12 setImage:Pic1];
        //score1=score1+10;
    }
    else if (intersectionCount1 == 2) {
        UIImage *Pic2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number2.png"];
        [correctCounter12 setImage:Pic2];
        //score1=score1+10;
    }
    else if (intersectionCount1 == 3) {
        UIImage *Pic3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number3.png"];
        [correctCounter12 setImage:Pic3];
        // score1=score1+10;
    }
    else if (intersectionCount1 == 4) {
        UIImage *Pic4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number4.png"];
        [correctCounter12 setImage:Pic4];
        // score1=score1+10;
    }
```

Code to set draggable `imageView` locations and put them in an arrays.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *myTouch =[[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint location= [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([myTouch view]==symbol1) {
        symbol1.center=location;
    }else if([myTouch view]==symbol12){
        symbol12.center=location;
    }else if([myTouch view]==symbol13){
        symbol13.center=location;
    }else if([myTouch view]==symbol14){
        symbol14.center=location;

    self.symbols1 =  @[symbol1, symbol12, symbol13, symbol14, symbol15, symbol16, symbol17, symbol18, symbol19];
    self.symbols2 =  @[symbol2, symbol22, symbol23, symbol24, symbol25, symbol26, symbol27, symbol28, symbol29, symbol210];
    self.symbols3 =  @[symbol3, symbol32, symbol33, symbol34, symbol35, symbol36, symbol37, symbol38, symbol39];
    self.symbols4 =  @[symbol4, symbol42, symbol43, symbol44, symbol45, symbol46, symbol47, symbol48];
```

Note that I didn't add the whole code for different imageViews as it is same and would take a lot of lines of code.

EDIT SOLUTION:
I figured out what caused it. I needed to set CGPoint for each `imageView` so it would reset back to its position. It seems simulator does it automatically where iPad needs code for that.

Comment: How can anyone answer this? Please add some specific details

Comment: welcome to the virtual world of iOS Simulators.

Comment: I added some details on how my app works, and how it works differently on iPad

Comment: Much more detail required with code and the logic that you used.

Comment: Add relevant code to the question. It is all about the code and there is none. The Simulator is very good and generally is not substantially different from the device. Best bet is that the problem is in the code, that is where I find my problems are. You will have to add relevant portions.

Comment: You may be running on a different OS version with lots of possible consequences. There may be timing issues, where your code only works on a fast device. There may be undefined behaviour, where anything can go wrong. To avoid that, turn on all warnings and fix all warnings.

Comment: I'd concentrate on just debugging the code, and not on why there is a difference between device and simulator. When you find the bug, it may be obvious where the difference comes from.

Comment: A good starting point would be to identify the specific actions that vary from simulator to device. The best way to do this would be to put in a breakpoint and step through it on the simulator and on the device.